# Meteor how to add findParams in find collection?

Tags: meteor

I am working on to show all users posts on the home page and it's working fine. I have added small buttons with posts
  so that user can block the post if he wants and block the user who has added that post and saving these values in users collection. All posts are coming on the home page but after block the argument or users I do not want to show that specific post or user post. This is my code to show all post and I am trying to add a condition in all posts code to not show block posts and block users posts.
This is my helper

```
'posts'() {
      const findParams = {};
    findParams.$or = [{ 'block': { $exists: false } }, { 'block': false }];
    if(Meteor.user()){
      let blockPost = Meteor.user().blockPostList;
      let blockUser = Meteor.user().blockOwneUserList;
      if(blockPost && blockPost.length > 0){
        findParams._id = { $nin: blockPost };
      }
      if(blockUser && blockUser.length > 0){
        findParams.$and = [{'plaintiff._id': {$nin: blockUser}},{'defendant._id': {$nin: blockUser}}];
      }
    }

    return Posts.find({}); 

},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are anyway always returning all documents, because

```
return Posts.find({});
```

returns everything that is currently in the Collection. It should rather be

```
return Posts.find(findParams);
```

Otherwise the whole code to build `findParams` makes no sense. Note, that not all mongo operations work on Minimongo (the Meteor client Mongo) but you should be fine with the ones in your code.